# Procurar conteúdo dentro de duas tags html - Regex

Tags: php, regex

Tenho uma página HTML em uma variável string. Preciso procurar dentro das tags h2 de todo documento se existe a palavra "Blog". Estou usando o pregmatch mas não consigo criar a expressão pra encontrar.

Podem me ajudar mais uma vez?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `DOMDocument` para filtrar por `H2`.

Você não informou o HTML, portanto imagine isto:

```
<div id="content">


<h2>Blog</h2>
<p class="y">Isto é um blog</p>

<h2>Index</h2>
<p class="x">Isto é um Index</p>

</div>
```

No PHP use algo similar a isso:

```
  $seu_html =  '<div id="content"> <h2>Blog</h2> <p class="y">Isto é um blog</p><h2>Index</h2> <p class="x">Isto é um Index</p></div>';

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($seu_html);

  // Todos os H2
  $h2 = $doc->getElementsByTagName("h2");

  // Loop de todos os H2
  foreach($h2 as $item){

      // Echo se encontrar a palavra Blog   
      echo strpos(strtolower($item->textContent), 'blog') !== false ? 'Achamos um H2  blog' : '';       

  }
```

Você pode testar isso [clicando aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3641b42ea5a7270e142960e4abe614a877e06e0c)

A documentação do `DOMDocument` é extremamente ampla *(por mim acredito que não muito amigável!)* e possui muitas funções, talvez até alguma que remova a necessidade do `foreach`! Veja isso [clicando aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php) e [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domnode.php).

> **IMPORTANTE:** O `strpos` foi usado para que possa "conter" mas não necessariamente ser "igual" ou "idêntico". Por essa razão se o `H2` for "Blog do Zé", será VÁLIDO! O `strtolower` foi usado para tornar o texto em minusculo, dessa forma removendo o erro de "Blog" ser diferente de "blog", por exemplo.

### Se quiser ainda usar REGEX....

Utilize o `/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>/`, por exemplo:

```
  $seu_html =  '<div id="content"> <h2>Blog</h2> <p class="y">Isto é um blog</p><h2>Index</h2> <p class="x">Isto é um Index</p></div>';

  preg_match_all ("/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>/", $seu_html, $h2);

  // Loop de todos os H2
  foreach($h2[1] as $item){

      // Echo se encontrar a palavra Blog   
      echo strpos(strtolower($item), 'blog') !== false ? 'Achamos um H2  blog' : '';        

  }
```

Você pode testar isso [clicando aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d4646bf9132958dc9865a73b7ff6c1733bbbd30)